# Accessing Microsoft Graph API for excel data on using AJAX request

Tags: jquery, excel, ajax, api, microsoft-graph-api

```
function requestToken() {
        $.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": endpointUrl, // Pass your tenant name instead of sharepointtechie
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            "data": {
                "grant_type": "password",
                "client_id ": clientId, //Provide your app id
                "client_secret": clientSecret,
                "scope ": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
                "userName": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "password": "xxxxxxxx",
                "redirect_uri" : "xxxxxxx"
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                token = response.access_token;



                  $.ajax({
                      url: 'xxxxxx',
                      type: 'GET',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token + '');
                      },
                      data: {},
                      success: function (results) {
                          console.log(results);
                          debugger;
                      },
                      error: function (error) {
                          console.log("Error in getting data: " + error);
                      }
                  });
            }

        })
    }
```

I am meant to be making a request to the MS Graph Api in order to get cell and row data from an excel spreadsheet hosted on OneDrive.

That is all well and good, however I was wondering what would be the best practice in completing this problem.

I can write an AJAX request using the client-id and client-secret to authenticate the use, however this would then expose those credentials to the clients browser.

How could I still make the request to the API but keep the app credentials safe.

Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side requests from the browser wouldn't use a client secret, and instead would use the [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). You can read all the details of how that flow works at that link.

[MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) makes this easy to implement, and they have a number of samples in their repository.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Am I able to sign users in on behalf of another user using that implicit grant flow?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can't sign a user in as another user in any flow, meaning User A can't sign in and act as User B.